# I'm getting light and dark blue areas in the surface normals. Even after shading, the marks remain

Tags: rendering, normal-map

I'm encountering issues with surface normals. Despite trying various fixes, the problem persists - I'm getting light and dark blue areas in the surface normals. Even after shading, the marks remain. Any assistance would be appreciated.